# Slim Framework with ORM (Eloquent) connect multiple db

Tags: orm, eloquent, slim, multiple-databases

I am using Slim Framework with Eloquent 4.1.x as ORM for a project and need to connect to multiple databases.

I followed this [link](http://www.slimframework.com/2013/03/21/slim-and-laravel-eloquent-orm.html) to setup the ORM. But how can I connect to multiple databases by following the given tutorial?

In my models I have different files that are used for different tables in different databases.

Like the User.php file has the following,

```
<?php
namespace Service\Framework\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model {
  protected $table = 'users';
}
```

This class uses the users table in db_2 database. I want to switch from the default database db_1 in a method in this Class. Like,

```
<?php

namespace Service\Framework\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model {
  protected $table = 'users';

  public function getUsers() {
    // Switch the database to db_2
    $users = self::all();
    // Again switch back to default database db_1
    return $users;
  }
}
```

How can I do that? Please help me with some suggestions.

P.S: I am not using Capsule here.

**EDIT #1**
So the code I am using to setup a single connection is as follows,

```
$settings = array(
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'database' => 'db_1',
      'username' => 'dbuser',
      'password' => 'password',
      'charset'  => 'utf8',
      'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
      'prefix' => ''
    );

    // Bootstrap Eloquent ORM
    $container = new Container();
    $connFactory = new ConnectionFactory($container);
    $conn = $connFactory->make($settings);
    $resolver = new ConnectionResolver();
    $resolver->addConnection('default', $conn);
    $resolver->setDefaultConnection('default');
    Model::setConnectionResolver($resolver);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should setup multiple connections. After connections are set up you can instruct model to use specific connection with `$connection` propery.

```
namespace Service\Framework\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model {
  protected $connection = 'mysql2';
  protected $table = 'users';
}
```

In routes or controllers you can user `setConnection()` method.

```
$user = new User;
$user->setConnection('mysql2');
print_r($user->find(1));
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, one query though. How can I setup multiple connections with the code that I am using? Any guess? I have updated my question with the code snippet. Please suggest.

Comment: I do not really use Eloquent, but looking at the code most likely by making another $conn object, for example $conn2 with different $settings. Then call something like to $resolver->addConnection('mysql2', $conn2);

Comment: Mike, yes this solved my issue. Though I had to use Capsule later on but the basic idea was the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can connect to multiple databases with this simplified code:

```
$app = new \Slim\App([
    'db' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'products',
        'username'  => 'user',
        'password'  => 'pass',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ],
    'db_second' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'second',
        'username'  => 'user',
        'password'  => 'pass',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ],
]);

$container = $app->getContainer();

// connect to db with Illuminate larvel
$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection($container['settings']['db']);
$capsule->addConnection($container['settings']['db_second'], 'db_second');
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
/// END connect to db

// to accsess the $capsule with our container from our controllers
$container['db'] = function($container) use ($capsule){
    return $capsule;
};
```

and in the Model file put:

```
protected $connection = 'db_second';
```